# Windows 10-Restore User Folder on New Computer Without Initializing User

Tags: windows-10

I backed up the C:\Users\USERNAME folder from 20 users. Is there any way to restore these folders on the new computers without having users to login again? When they login again their profile will be initialized and a folder with their username is created, but I don't want to bother each user just to restore their data.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  As the manager of three different domains, is it really *that* much of a bother to ask an end-user to login briefly to aid in the profile restoration process?  I certainly wouldn't think so.  That being said, while we are always glad to help a question like this would probably be more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Yes, you're right it is not a critical issue, but we have more than 15,000 employees and I'm trying to save as much time as possible for my coworkers. Thank you for pointing me to Server Fault!

Comment: ServerFault is indeed a better forum for this kind of question. SU is typically more for non-business environments. Perhaps a mod will migrate the question, but I'd assume there's a preexisting answer for this on SF already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tool to do this is the [User State Migration Tool (USMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/getting-started-with-the-user-state-migration-tool). This is intended for mass deployments at the enterprise level, so 20 machines/profiles actually might not be enough to justify learning and using it (it's a [CLI utility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-command-line-syntax)), that is unless you will be doing this regularly. Alternatively, you can use [Microsoft's suggestion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview) for a 3rd party tool instead: [Laplink PCmover](https://pcmover-10.laplink.com/) (note: it is not free).